# How can I filter by date in datatable.net with 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables

I have already tried everything, trying to filter the dates, I am something new, the code is in datatable.net and the vue component

```
<input id="minDate" v-model="minDate" outlined raised class="btnDate" type="date" />
<input id="maxDate" v-model="maxDate" outlined raised class="btnDate" type="date" />
```

I have those 2 buttons

```
const minDate = ref('')
const maxDate = ref('')
```

these 2 variables

```
const dataTable = $('#miTabla').DataTable()

$(minDate).on('input change', function () {
  dataTable.column(7).search(minDate.value, false, true).draw()
})

$(maxDate).on('input change', function () {
  dataTable.column(7).search(maxDate.value, false, true).draw()
})
```

this is my code.

I already tried modifying everything, I don't know what else to do to make it work, I'm somewhat new to this, that's why it's hard for me.

```
function fechaReg(milisegundos) {
  // Crear una nueva instancia de Date a partir de los milisegundos
  const fecha = new Date(milisegundos)

  // Obtener la fecha en formato ISO (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sssZ)
  const fechaISO = fecha.toISOString()

  // Extraer la parte de la fecha (YYYY-MM-DD)
  const fechaFormateada = fechaISO.substring(0, 10)


  return fechaFormateada
}
```

I receive my date in milliseconds and convert it with this function

```
onValue(reff(database, 'users/'), (snapshot) => {
    const arreglo = []

    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      const entre = childSnapshot.val()

      if (entre.rol === 'Entrenador') {
        const attachments = [
          entre.estudios,
          entre.hojadevida,
          entre.otros,
          entre.cedula,
        ].filter(Boolean).length
        const documentos = `${attachments}/4`

        arreglo.push({
          UserID: entre.UserID,
          identificacion: entre.identificacion,
          nombres: entre.nombres,
          apellidos: entre.apellidos,
          nameUser: entre.nameUser,
          fecha_nacimiento: entre.fecha_nacimiento,
          telefono: entre.telefono,
          fecha_registro: fechaReg(entre.fecha_registro),
          estado: entre.estado,
          documentos: documentos,
        })
      }
    })

    deportistas.value = arreglo
  })
})
```

This is the path of the arrangement, I am trying to use the 2 buttons to filter element 7, any recommendations on how to do it, or what I am failing